# Saving a png with multhist and a legend

Tags: r, histogram, legend

The following code works when not saving a png (no dev.off() or png()) but otherwise produces one of two errors:

```
require(plotrix)
approaches = c("X", "Y", "Z")
lifespans <- list(c(1,2,3,4), c(3,4,5,6), c(1,6,4,1,1,3))
color.names <- c("grey24", "dark grey", "grey90")
png("lifespans_multhist.png")
multhist(lifespans, xlab="Lifespan / seconds", ylab="Frequency")
#legend("topright", approaches, fill=color.names)
dev.off()
```

I can't understand the errors. Sometimes one occurs and sometimes the other by running the code without any changes. Errors:

```
Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet

Error in is.matrix(height) && beside : invalid 'y' type in 'x && y'
```

RStudio displays the graph sometimes and not others. The program has never output the desired png. I've tried chaning the position of the legend generation and other variations but without success. I'm completely at a loss.

Edit: Updated code for minimum working example.

Comment: I believe legend() isn't meant to be called without a plot already present, it gets confused as to where to go on the device region ("topright" of what?)

Comment: I suspected this and tried putting it after the multhist but without success. Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: please post a minimal self-contained reproducible example, including any package that needs to be loaded (plotrix?)

Comment: Done. I can save without the legend but not with it. I keep getting the new.plot error.

Comment: your code works for me